# My fstream always returns true, even with bad file name?

Tags: c++

This is my first question, and i seriously cannot figure this out.  After debugging I realize that no matter what gets put into outFileName and in turn outFile, it always returns true and will not display the error message.  Sorry if I have left anything out this is c++ I am using visual studio 2010 let me know if I need to add anything to the question.

```
        inFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);
        outFile.open(outFileName.c_str(), ios::out);
        if (inFile.good() == false && outFile.good() == false)
        {
            cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
            cerr << "Problem with the input and output file" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        else if (inFile.good() == true &&
                 outFile.good() == false)
        {
            cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
            cerr << "Problem with the output file";
            continue;
        }
        else if (outFile.good() == true &&
                inFile.good() == false)
        {
            cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
            cerr << "Problem with the input file" << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Out files are just that -- output. They don't have to exist, and you can enter pretty much anything and it'll work. What's the confusion there?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete, program that demonstrates the problem. Without knowing more about your program, any answer will necessarily be a guess. See http://sscce.org for more information about how to create short, complete example programs.

Comment: i thought that the program had to establish a connection with an existing file for output, but if anything would work, how would I program this to report an error message?

Comment: you can test booleans directly...don't compare to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write to an existing file, you probably want to either erase the existing content (overwrite it), or else add to the end.  So reasonable flags would be:

```
outFile.open(outFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

or

```
outFile.open(outFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::app | ios::ate);
```

These will require that the file already exist.

After that, `outFile.good()` returns a boolean which you can test directly.  Don't compare it to `true`.  After all, if `outFile.good() == true` is true, then `outFile.good()` must have been true.  In fact, there's an explicit conversion to boolean for the stream, as well as user-defined `operator!()`.  So your error-checking could look like this:

```
if (!inFile) {
    if (!outFile) {
        cerr << strerror(errno) << endl
             << "Problem with the input and output file" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cerr << strerror(errno) << endl
             << "Problem with the input file";
    }
}
else if (!outFile) {
    cerr << strerror(errno) << endl
         << "Problem with the output file" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to open a file for writing the it will never fail.

Try opening a file in a location you are not allowed to open.

Comment: but even if I just type in gibberish outFile.good() still returns true.

Comment: It depends upon the gibberish. Try `"c:\\blah\\gorg\\foo.txt"`, after making sure that the directory `c:\blah` does not exist. Or, try `"\"!@#$%^&<>?*():::'"`.

Comment: Define gibberish. What may seem strange to you may be perfectly OK. When say things like that you need to be specific. We are not mind readers. I tried 'FooBar' and it worked (looks like gibberish to me but fine for a file system).